# Multi-join query to return record for the most recently shipped product

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

My purpose is to create a catalog of my company's products. Most of our products have multiple id's and product #s (product.num), but a product's description is the same across all of its possible IDs and #s. I am able to return a list of our product names and the correct last ship date, but the product numbers returned are not the actual most recent # (they do belong to that product, they just aren't the most recent one shipped). Here is the query as it stands now:

```
SELECT part.num, part.description, product.upc, vendorparts.lastCost, producttree.name, Max(ship.dateShipped)

FROM ship
LEFT JOIN shipitem ON ship.id = shipitem.shipid
LEFT JOIN soitem ON shipitem.soitemid = soitem.id
LEFT JOIN product ON soitem.productid = product.id
LEFT JOIN producttotree ON product.id = producttotree.productid 
LEFT JOIN producttree ON producttotree.producttreeid = producttree.id
LEFT JOIN part ON product.partid = part.id
LEFT JOIN vendorparts ON part.id = vendorparts.partid

GROUP BY product.description
```

Comment: what version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: 5.7 is what my database dictionary indicates, but I'm also using Microsoft Query in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 8, MySQL supports window functions

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    FIRST_VALUE(part.num) OVER (PARTITION BY product.description ORDER BY ship.dateShipped DESC) as num,
    FIRST_VALUE(part.description) OVER (PARTITION BY product.description ORDER BY ship.dateShipped DESC) as description,
    FIRST_VALUE(product.upc) OVER (PARTITION BY product.description ORDER BY ship.dateShipped DESC) as upc,
    FIRST_VALUE(vendorparts.lastCost) OVER (PARTITION BY product.description ORDER BY ship.dateShipped DESC) as lastCost,
    FIRST_VALUE(producttree.name) OVER (PARTITION BY product.description ORDER BY ship.dateShipped DESC) as name,
    FIRST_VALUE(ship.dateShipped) OVER (PARTITION BY product.description ORDER BY ship.dateShipped DESC) as dateShipped
FROM ship
LEFT JOIN shipitem ON ship.id = shipitem.shipid
LEFT JOIN soitem ON shipitem.soitemid = soitem.id
LEFT JOIN product ON soitem.productid = product.id
LEFT JOIN producttotree ON product.id = producttotree.productid 
LEFT JOIN producttree ON producttotree.producttreeid = producttree.id
LEFT JOIN part ON product.partid = part.id
LEFT JOIN vendorparts ON part.id = vendorparts.partid
```